# How do I find the weights of the features after obtaining a model using svmtrain in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

Currently, the model returns a model of type structure having the following properties:

SupportVectors 
KernelFunction
KernelFunctionArgs 
GroupNames
SupportVectorIndices
ScaleData

More details here:

http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/svmtrain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used any non-linear kernel then obtaining feature weights is quite complex (it is possible, but far beyond simple).

In case of linear kernel you can retrieve the weight wector from the equation

```
w = SUM_i alpha_i SV_i
```

where `alpha_i` is a `i` support vector weight (from the struct; its sign corresponds to the label of the training sample) and `SV_i` is `i` support vector.

Comment: I am using a linear kernel.

But that would mean the weight vector is of the size of support vector only. I would want the weight for each feature.

For example, consider a dataset with N observations each with D dimensions. The size of the weight vector should be D*1. However, the solution suggested by you will give me only M*1 weight vector where M is the number of support vectors.

Comment: you are wrong. each support vector has a size of the feature space, you compute their linear combination, which is still the size of the feature space (D).

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. :) 

I am sorry I cannot up-vote your answer because I have limited repute.